# How to set the content type of flight framework response

Tags: php, android, json

I am writing a restful webservice for my android app, and i am using flight php framework to route url. i have written a simple code shown below to return a json payload posted to the server instead it returns an html content type instead of a json. Please guys how to i change the response content-type to json, thanks in advance.

My code here:

```
 include ('lib/flight/autoload.php');
 include ('TestClass.php');

 use flight\Engine;

 $app = new Engine();

 $app->_route('/', 'hello');

$app->_route('/user', array('TestClass', 'hello'));


$app->_start();

function hello(){
$request = Flight::request()->getBody();

 echo json_encode($request);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

@julianm is almost correct.

```
Flight::json($response);
```

But `echo` function is not needed.

source: http://flightphp.com/learn#json

Answer (score 1):

```
header( "Content-type:  application/json" );
echo json_encode( $request );
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a JSON response with FlightPHP, you can use something like:

```
$response = array('id'=>1, 'website'=>'http://slidehunter.com');
echo Flight::json($response);
```